# CSS3 animation called twice for same element

Tags: animation, css

I have the following problem. I wanna reuse the same animation two times, with different delays on the same element. I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
.myClass{
    -webkit-animation: animationName 1s linear 2s, animationName 1s linear 4s;
}
```

The strange thing, and what I don't get is that if I create a second animation, say "animationName2" with the same content like animationName then the following would work:

```
.myClass{
    -webkit-animation: animationName 1s linear 2s, animationName2 1s linear 4s;
}
```

Am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [css-infos.net](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-animation) there should be 6 attributes. you have 4.

These are:

```
-webkit-animation: <name> <duration> <timing_function> <delay> <iteration_count> <direction>
```

I guess  there are default values for the iteration count and direction, but CSS is a biatch some days.  I take it that your actual class is called what you think it's called `myClass` in this case?  All the usual debugging stuff.